# du on Mac OS 10.9 gives two different answers for the same directory

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, du

If I run `du` on my `iMovie Library.imovielibrary` I can get two different results depending on how I run `du`. However, I believe both of these should result in the same value. Behold:

```
davids-imac:Movies david$ du -s iMovie\ Library.imovielibrary
33069784    iMovie Library.imovielibrary
davids-imac:Movies david$ du -s * | grep iMovie\ Library.imovielibrary
9816792 iMovie Library.imovielibrary
davids-imac:Movies david$ cd iMovie\ Library.imovielibrary/
davids-imac:iMovie Library.imovielibrary david$ du -s .
33069784    .
```

33069784 vs 9816792? Huh?!?

If I copy this bundle to another 10.9 machine using ditto over AFP it shows the correct value regardless.

The only thing I can think of is there's some sort of file system corruption or possibly compression at work that ditto didn't pick up on. Or using `*` somehow treats bundles differently? But I would expect that to happen on my other machine, too, then.

Any ideas?